# i have start date&time and end date&time...i need the difference between start and end

Tags: sql, date

I have start date&time and end date&time. I need the difference between these two and  when end date&time is null then i need the differ between start date&time and current date&time...... Thanks in advance.

```
select pwr.ondate ONDATE,pwr.offdate OFFDATE,mp.process FROMPROCESS,
    (select mp.process   from mas_process mp where pwr.protoid=mp.p_id) TOPROCESS,
    USEDHOURS = case when pwr.offdate is null then 
        datediff(HH,pwr.ondate,getdate()) else
        datediff(d,pwr.ondate,pwr.offdate)
    end 
from powerreport pwr
inner join mas_process mp on pwr.proid=mp.p_id
```

Comment: Exactly what issue are you observing with your query? Aside from the fact you are returning the difference in hours when you don't have an end date and the difference in days when you do have an end date the time calculation portion of this looks correct. Maybe you could simplify it to `USEDHOURS = datediff(HH,pwr.ondate,IsNull(pwr.offdate, getDate()))` if you wanted to return the difference in hours in both cases.

Comment: same thing i used for minute but i get the ans is like 223,340 but i need 13.40,14.50 like.........

Comment: i used this coding i got the anser as 1:233,2:998 but i need as 1:50,4:37 like                                             'USEDHOURS = case when pwr.offdate is null then 
(SELECT 
 CAST(DATEDIFF(hh,pwr.ondate, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + ':' +
 CAST(DATEDIFF(mi,pwr.ondate, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
) 
else 
(SELECT 
 CAST(DATEDIFF(hh,pwr.ondate, pwr.offdate) AS VARCHAR) + ':' +
 CAST(DATEDIFF(mi,pwr.ondate, pwr.offdate) AS VARCHAR) 
) end'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express the difference between two datetimes in the format hour:minute you can obtain the minute portion by first calculating the total number of minutes between the two datetimes using datediff like you were: `datediff(MI, startDate, endDate)` and then calculating modulos 60 against the results of the datediff.

The [modulo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator in SQL Server is % so the expression for this would be `datediff(MI, startDate, endDate) % 60`

I would suggest creating a local variable and populating it with the results of a `GETDATE()` call so all rows in your results are calculated using the exact same datetime for cases when the end date for a particular record is null. Additionally you can simplify the query if you use [`IsNull()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) against the end date and have it return current time if the end date is null.

If you put all three of those together you would have a query that looks something like the following to calculate the difference for all records in your powerreport table:

```
DECLARE @currentTime AS DATETIME;

SET @currentTime = GETDATE();

SELECT *,
       USEDHOURS = 
       CAST (datediff(HH, pwr.ondate, 
             IsNull(pwr.offdate, @currentTime)) AS VARCHAR) + ':' +
       CAST (datediff(MI, pwr.ondate, 
             IsNull(pwr.offdate, @currentTime)) % 60 AS VARCHAR)
FROM   powerreport AS pwr;
```

Here is a SQL Fiddle showing this in action: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e47af/1

And if you plugged this into your original query the result should be something like the following:

```
DECLARE @currentTime AS DATETIME;

SET @currentTime = GETDATE();

SELECT pwr.ondate AS ONDATE,
       pwr.offdate AS OFFDATE,
       mp.process AS FROMPROCESS,
       (SELECT mp.process
        FROM   mas_process AS mp
        WHERE  pwr.protoid = mp.p_id) AS TOPROCESS,
       USEDHOURS = 
       CAST (datediff(HH, pwr.ondate,
             IsNull(pwr.offdate, @currentTime)) AS VARCHAR) + ':' +
       CAST (datediff(MI, pwr.ondate,
             IsNull(pwr.offdate, @currentTime)) % 60 AS VARCHAR)
FROM   powerreport AS pwr
       INNER JOIN
       mas_process AS mp
       ON pwr.proid = mp.p_id;
```

Comment: Here us a SQL Fiddle to go with the first code example in my answer: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e47af/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e47af/1) perhaps you could create a SQL Fiddler containing the DDL for both your powereport and mas_process tables and a small sample of the data in each and add it to your question?